# Trying to get a handle on Rxjs, how would you do something like this

Tags: rxjs

I'm somewhat getting the hang of rxjs, but trying to implement it into a real project, I can't figure out where to start. So this is what I want to do.

1. Use fs to read a dir, and get all the files in there
2. Run some function that'll parse one file at a time and build an insert statement for mysql
3. Take that statement run it and when it succeeds, start again with a different file (or preferrably run about 10 of these concurrently )

My thought process is, Make an observable stream from the files array and then have the subscription do the insert. But how do you make it go one by one and wait till the previous insert succeeds. Adding to that, how do you do like 10 of these concurrently? Can anyone direct me the right way?

Comment: start with rxjs docs, there are a bunch of resources for learning there, you should find links to articles going in detail with some examples, then try to write some code (you have a thought process, make that a code process) and try some debugging. When you have a specific question, search SO, a lot of issues have already been detailed in here, including ones that are very similar to yours. If you can't find a solution, post back your issue here.

Answer (score 1):

rxjs is a great tool to manage asynchronous code. Unless you definitely need concurrency or asynchronous handling, I would simply use procedural or functional programming and leave rxjs out of the equation.

That being said, there are use cases, possibly even yours, that does require some sort of asynchronous handling of reading files, processing them and then maybe acting on them, some or all parts of the process being asynchronous.

You could write an observable streaming with **.next()** the file names, or use **Observable.of(arrayOfFileNames)** and then **.map()** the filenames into their contents, then **.map()** the contents into your generated SQL queries and **.subscribe()** to this stream of SQL queries to run each SQL query.

Error handling in rxjs at a point in the chain would trigger the error portion (2nd parameter) of the **.subscribe()** call or could be caught be a **.error()** in the chain. Note however that unless you isolate parts of the chain for potential errors, any error will discard all parts upstream of the error and only forward down the error to the subscriber. The entire chain then dies at the first error without explicit isolation.

Note that even though I have specifically said rxjs is a great tool for managing asynchronous code only, by default, rxjs uses a synchronous scheduler and the chain and subscription would happen "in a blocking" manner. You can choose a different scheduler by adding it as the last parameter of your **Observable.of()** for example.